# A way to access all my form elements without creating different functions for different ids

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project for my web design class. We have to make a website for a fake company, not really important info. This is combined HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Anyway, so I'm making an order page with a form and everything, and I have a ton of fieldsets all with different ids, since they all ask different questions. I want to display one fieldset at a time, and have a "Next" button that will hide the current fieldset and display the next one. So each fieldset will be set to

```
display: none;
```

until you press the button. I was going to use javascript

```
document.getElementById("").style.display = "block";
```

to do this. But I just started learning javascript a couple days ago and I'm not sure how to do this with so many different ids. I don't want to have create a different function for each fieldset. I have a total of 24. I don't think an array would work, nor incrementing a numeric id, cause these don't function as numbers right? Sorry, I'm very new to JavaScript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect a little dom traversal would simplify things, removing the dependence on selecting elements on ID's. though i'm not sure if that'd be more advanced than what your project is looking for. Maybe it does simply want you to do a bunch of id lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something simple to get you going.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
  function NextClicked(incomingStepID)
  {
      document.getElementById("question" + incomingStepID).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("question" + (incomingStepID + 1)).style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("buttonToClick").setAttribute("onclick", "NextClicked(" + (incomingStepID + 1) + ")");
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="NextHolder"><button type="submit" id="buttonToClick" onclick="NextClicked(1);">next</button></div>
  <div id="question1" style="display: block">q1</div>
  <div id="question2" style="display: none">q2</div>
  <div id="question3" style="display: none">q3</div>
  <div id="question4" style="display: none">q4</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Really neat! This is assuming that the Ids are identical besides a lagging increment number.

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by setting up all visibility stuff in CSS using classes.  Something like:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Put your fieldsets in order of display, with all set to hidden except the first:

```
<fieldset>
...
  <button onclick='next(event)'>Next</button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='hidden'>
...
</fieldset>
```

Now, ideally you'd associate the click handler in JS rather than on the HTML page, but keeping things simple, you'd do it like above.  The next function then just needs to get the next fieldset and clear the classname while setting its own fieldset's classname to 'hidden'.

```
function next(event) {
  var self = event.target;
  var parent = self.parentNode;
  var nextFieldset = self.nextSibling;
  parent.className = 'hidden';
  nextFieldset.className = '';
}
```

Didn't get a chance to test it, but that should get you in the ballpark.